# If Time is more then a set time than show a message

Tags: php, html

I am writing an attendance script and basically trying to figure out if a certain time of a user is exceeds from a set time then display a message like "You are late"

I somehow succeeded in showing a message but I think there is some error in my code since it is showing some irregular results. Also it doesn't show how much time a user got late.

My PHP code;

```
if ($a['enter_time'] > strtotime('20:00:00'))
    {
        $late_time = date('h:i', $a['enter_time'] - strtotime('20:00:00'));
        $late_time_bit = '<tr><td class="late_time" align="center" colspan="2">You are '.$late_time.' minute(s) late.</td></tr>';
    }
```

Here, `$a['enter_time']` is DB UNIX time stamp value. This the result I get so far;
[image]

You can see that the user is actually `1 hour and 36 minutes` late but the code running is showing an irregular result.

I want if that DB time is greater than a set time time (let say, 8:00 PM) than it shows a message that you are late and also how much hours/minutes you are late. Please help.

Comment: What is the exact value of `$a['enter_time']`?

Comment: @aynber: This--> 1658853416

Comment: It's probably timezone related. Try adding `echo "(".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a['enter_time']) ." vs ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('20:00:00')).")";` to see what you get. With your values, I'm getting `(2022-07-26 12:36:56 vs 2022-07-25 20:00:00)`.

Comment: A five hour difference might happen due to timezone applied. See: `php > echo date('r', strtotime('20:00:00')); // Tue, 26 Jul 2022 20:00:00 +0700` - I get a timestamp for that hour in my timezone -- at +7 hours from UTC. Compare: `php > echo date('r', strtotime('20:00:00 UTC')); // Wed, 27 Jul 2022 03:00:00 +0700`

Comment: Is there any way I could get the time difference between user `DB enter_time` and the set time e.g. 8:00 AM

Comment: Note, it's probably dangerous to use `strtotime('20:00:00')` without a day indicator. For example, if the user clocks in after midnight, and this code runs when they clock in, then `strtotime('20:00:00')` will give you 8pm _for the next day_, and the user will be marked 20 hours early instead of 4 hours late.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Sorry, but how can I use day indicator in the given code?

Comment: You need to know what day and time the user is supposed to clock in, not just what time. Once you have that info, you can provide it to the strtotime() function or the DateTime class like `strtotime('2022-07-24 20:00:00')` or `new DateTime('2022-07-24 20:00:00')`.

Comment: @aynber yes indeed, OP is at GMT+5, so the "irregular result" with a five-hour difference from UTC/timestamp naturally follows when `strtotime` is used without timezone specified (and as such PHP/system default timezone is used, which OP likely has at Pakistan).